# template class alias inside other class body produces compilation error

Tags: c++

I am working on `Visual Studio 2015 community edition`.

The following code produces an error:

```
#include <list>
using std::list;

template <typename T>
class enumerator
{
// typedef: 
public:
    using list_      = list<T*>;                        // line:
    using list_fwd_c = list_::const_iterator;           // 188
    using list_fwd   = list_::iterator;                 // 189
    using list_rvs_c = list_::const_reverse_iterator;   // 190
    using list_rvs   = list_::reverse_iterator;         // 191
};                                                      // 192
```

and the error:

```
1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(188): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'const_iterator'

1>  d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(192): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'cpplib::eval::utils::enumerator<T>' being compiled

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(188): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(189): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'iterator'

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(189): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(190): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'const_reverse_iterator'

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(190): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(191): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'reverse_iterator'

1>d:\develop\workspace\visual_studio\nevada_test_site\source\shared\cpp\expression_evaluator\expression_evaluator\src\expr_eval.cpp(191): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I have confirmed this is the troublesome code piece (error disappear when I comment out the 'enumerator' class).

As its name suggests, it "will be" a simple enumerator class (something like a `IEnumerator` from `C#`. I will use it in order to store a list of objects derived from a base class passed as a class template parameter `T`.

**Question:** 
 1. Why the code above produces this error.
 2. How can I fix this error? 
 3. I know this is not a place for this, but if you know a good implementation (`boost` ?) for this kind of enumerator, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to add a `typename` despite how convenient `using` is:

```
using list_fwd_c = typename list_::const_iterator;           // 188
using list_fwd   = typename list_::iterator;                 // 189
using list_rvs_c = typename list_::const_reverse_iterator;   // 190
using list_rvs   = typename list_::reverse_iterator;         // 191
```

The problem is that these are **dependent types** (they depend on the template parameter) so the compiler cannot just know they are all types (and not, say functions or static data members)

Comment: No, there isn't any problem with `std::list`. I included this header

Comment: @cukier9a7b5: Okay, I removed that part. In the future you can help us answer better by specifying that sort of information. Read about producing a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I didn't think that this could be an issue.